# MongoDB: create text index for multiple field each one in a different language

Tags: mongodb

Using the example from [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/control-results-of-text-search/), suppose that I have the *content* field in English and *about* field in Portuguese. How do I create the text index specifying one language for each field?

```
db.blog.createIndex(
   {
     content: "text",
     keywords: "text",
     about: "text"
   },
   {
     weights: {
       content: 10,
       keywords: 5
     },
     name: "TextIndex"
   }
 )
```

Comment: That doesn't appear to be possible. In my experience, mongodb is not so great for text indexing. Have you considered using elasticsearch?

Comment: @lyjackal It's very possible, and has been so for some time. That said MongoDB is not a "sole purpose" text indexer, as are most general databases also not suited to "specialized" tasks. Specific use cases are far better suited to dedicated text search products. But simple indexing of content in varying languages is not a problem here.

Comment: @Neil Lunn thanks, I stand corrected. Good to know

Comment: I have not considered elasticsearch. For now I was just interested in the mongodb full text search. But thank you both.